# Python3 - Parse list of strings inside nested json

Tags: python, json, list, python-3.7

Python Noob here. I saw many similar questions but none of it my exact use case. I have a simple nested json, and I'm trying to access the element `name` present inside `metadata`. Below is my sample json.

```
{
    "items": [{
            "metadata": {
                "name": "myname1"
            }
        },
        {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "myname1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is the code That I have tried so far, but not successfull.

```
import json
f = open('./myfile.json')
x = f.read()
data = json.loads(x)
for i in data['items']:
    for j in i['metadata']:
            print (j['name'])
```

It errors out stating below

> File "pythonjson.py", line 8, in 
> print (j['name']) TypeError: string indices must be integers

When I printed `print (type(j))` I received the following o/p `<class 'str'>`. So I can see that it is a list of strings and not an dictinoary. So now How can I parse through a list of strings? Any official documentation or guide would be much helpful to know the concept of this.

Comment: Try to convert the nested element into json too --> `print(json.loads(j)['name']`

Comment: The `JSON` provided is not valid. Also you likely need `print(item['metadata']['name'])` in the first for loop. No second loop required.

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: Missing `:` aside, nested JSON would be something like `{"foo": "{\"bar\": 5}"}`, where the value of the `foo` key can itself be decoded. What you have is just a "plain" JSON object that when decoded, produces a nested data structure in whatever language you used to decode it.

Comment: Sorry for posting an invalid Json. Have corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is bad, and the python exception is clear and unambiguous. You have the basic string "name" and you are trying to ... do a lookup on that?

Let's cut out all the json and look at the real issue. You do not know how to iterate over a dict. You're actually iterating over the keys themselves. If you want to see their values too, you're going to need dict.items()

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

```
metadata = {"name": "myname1"}
for key, value in metadata.items():
    if key == "name":
        print ('the name is', value)
```

But why bother if you already know the key you want to look up?
This is literally why we have dict.

```
print ('the name is', metadata["name"])
```

Comment: I used to iterate through dict objects like I did in my question for boto3 (AWS Python SDK) and I was able to access the values too without any hiccups. So I thought I was doing things correctly, but your reply makes more sense. Will have to relook on my python basics. Sorry for the json. Has been corrected now.

Comment: If you're using that code, you're just iterating through the keys. But that doesn't change the fact that you can use those keys to look up their values, so there's that.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong, From this I've learnt one thing. Whenever I arrive at a string object inside a dict, Then it's time to stop iterating and I can directly call them . Right?

Comment: If you already know what key you're looking for, then do not iterate to find it. Just use it directly. (if you're worried about it not being in there, check for or handle that, don't iterate)

Comment: but yes, you "can" iterate to find it. But that is inefficient, potentially crippling -- you'll learn big-O notation later.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need:

```
import json
f = open('./myfile.json')
x = f.read()
data = json.loads(x)
for item in data['items']:
    print(item["metadata"]["name"]
```

Your original `JSON` is not valid (colons missing).

Comment: Sorry, Json is corrected now. Coming to the solution, So when we hit strings inside json (or dictionary) We should not iterate further right? We should access them directly? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

to access contents of name use "i["metadata"].keys()" this will return all keys in "metadata".

Working code to access all values of the dictionary in "metadata".

```
for i in data['items']:
    for j in i["metadata"].keys():
        print (i["metadata"][j])
```

**update:**Working code to access contents of "name" only.

```
for i in data['items']:
        print (i["metadata"]["name"])
```

Comment: Nice way! this will solve this question. but won't produce the expected output when there are multiple keys inside `metadata`. It needs to be tweaked a bit I guess.